# Find the most unique characters in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Recently joined a python code club, so not a school assignment.

Task:

> Write a function `coolest_word(words)` that returns the coolest word if it exists.
>
> The coolness is defined by how many unique characters a word has.
>
> For example the word `"decomposition"` has a `10` unique letters.
>   Your job is to find from the given list of words the coolest word and return it.
>
> If the list is empty, return `None`. If there is a tie, return one of the words.

My solution up till now:

```
words = ['expectation', 'discomfort', 'half', 'decomposition']
def coolest_word(words):
    length = 0
    unique = ['']
    for i in words:
        if (len(words) != 0 and len(set(i)) > length):
            length = len(set(i))
            unique[0] = i
        else:
            unique[0] = ('None')
    return(unique)  
print(coolest_word(words))
```

I've chosen to change `list` to `set` and afterwards compare unique characters of a `set` with each other. As `set` does not take into account duplicate variables it seemed like a good idea.

Whenever for loop finds a longer set(with more variables) it is overwritten into unique set to be memorized and later called upon.

The problem right now is that if the given list is empty unique returns `['']`, which I do not understand why.

As in the second part if the list is empty I want unique to be overwritten, but it does not do so.

Any thoughts?

Comment: if the list is empty going in then you never enter your loop so your unique is `unique = ['']` that's not empty, that's a list containing one empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input list `words` is empty, i.ee, `words=[]`, you will not go inside the for loop. And you are not defining what should happen to `unique` incase input list is empty.

Try this:

```
words = ['expectation', 'discomfort', 'half', 'decomposition']
def coolest_word(words):
    length = 0
    unique = ['']

    if not words:    # If input list is empty set unique as None.
        unique[0] = 'None'    

    for i in words:
        if (len(words) != 0 and len(set(i)) > length):
            length = len(set(i))
            unique[0] = i
        else:
            unique[0] = ('None')
    return(unique)  
print(coolest_word(words))
```

But a better way I can suggest would be to initialize the `unique` list with `None`, i.e. `unique = ['None']` instead of `unique = ['']`. This way you can keep all your code as it is.

Comment: could you explain what "if not words:" does in this case?

Comment: This checks if the list `word` is empty or contains any element. It is same as we check `length of list > 0`.

Comment: wow, your suggestion..that is something I should have come up with myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Simple application of [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with both `key` and `default`.

```
def coolest_word(words):
    return max(words, key=lambda w: len(set(w)), default=None)
```

Demo:

```
>>> coolest_word(['expectation', 'discomfort', 'half', 'decomposition'])
'decomposition'

>>> [coolest_word([])]   # Wrap in a list because None by itself doesn't get printed
[None]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set` to get unique elements in a word and `len` to find out how many unique elements are in word.

```
words = ['expectation', 'discomfort', 'half', 'decomposition']

def coolest_word(wlist):
    k = {i:len(set(i)) for i in wlist}
    return max(k, key=k.get)

print(coolest_word(words))
```

Output:

```
'decomposition'
```

**Explanation**

if you do `print(k)` it will give you

```
{'expectation': 9, 'discomfort': 9, 'half': 4, 'decomposition': 10}
```

`max(k, key=k.get)` will return a key with highest value(max value),

`k.get` will get the values for a key

eg.

```
print(k.get("half"))
```

output:

```
4
```

Comment: btw, we were suggested to use max, key= function, but I failed to understand it. If you could explain it a bit more, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

If the given list is empty, the entire for loop is skipped. So you just have to initialize `unique` this way:

```
unique = ['None']
```

Also you have to remove the `else` branch inside the for loop, because it would overwrite the result as soon as you find a word having no duplicate letters (to test what I'm saying, try to shuffle the input list this way:

```
words = ['expectation', 'discomfort', 'decomposition', 'half']
```

and you would get 'None' instead of 'decomposition'.

ADDENDUM: you can even simplify your if condition, replacing

```
if (len(words) != 0 and len(set(i)) > length)
```

with

```
if (len(set(i)) > length)
```

because if `len(words)` were actually `0` you wouldn't even enter the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

very simple approach using unordered_set in c++. Check code below:

#include 
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string coolestword(vector wordList) {

```
if(wordList.empty()) return "None";

int length = 0;
string retStr = "None";
for(string word : wordList) {
    unordered_set<char> tempSet;
    for(int i=0; i<word.size(); i++){
        tempSet.insert(word[i]);
    }
    if(length<tempSet.size()) {
        length = tempSet.size();
        retStr = word;
    }
}

return retStr;
```

}

int main()
{
vector wordList = {"expectation", "discomfort", "half", "decomposition"};
std::cout << coolestword(wordList) << std::endl;
return 0;
}

Comment: Obviously, this answer is not Pythonic.